# nodemcu with Lua and 8266 tmr.stop

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Note: This is a copy of a question asked [here](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=79610)

Hi

I am completely new to EPS8266 and Lua (but not to programming - my first CPU was an 8080...)
Using a nodemcu HUZZA from adafruit

Anyway I am testing some timer stuff and running into this:

```
tmr.alarm(0, 500, 1, function()
  print("I'm here")
  tmr.stop(0)
end)
```

Without the stop, the loop keeps printing, with it the `tmr.stop(0)` stops.    ... so far so good.

But if I want to start the timer again like:

```
tmr.alarm(0, 500, 1, function()
  print("I'm here")
  tmr.stop(0)

  -- do some stuff

  tmr.start(0)
 end)
```

I get an error: `PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API...`

The documentation says that the `tmr` is still registered when `stop` is called.

A call to `tmr.state(0)` does the same. Only `tmr.stop(0)` seems to works as expected.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Probably, `tmr.start` is not allowed inside timer callback function?

Comment: @I0sens any further input required here?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/tmr) says to no longer use static timers

> Static timers are deprecated and will be removed later. Use the OO API initiated with `tmr.create()`.

If you want complete control over when the functions in the timer callback are executed you need a `ALARM_SEMI` instance upon which you call `start` whenever needed. It'll fire exactly once for every time you call `start` on it.

```
local mytimer = tmr.create()
mytimer:register(500, tmr.ALARM_SEMI, function() print("I'm here") end)
-- do stuff here
-- then whenever needed trigger the timer
mytimer:start()
```

Note that `mytimer` is not unregistered and not garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, you need to use tmr.ALARM_SEMI as your alarm mode.

ALARM_SEMI is described by the [documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/tmr/#tmralarm) as:

> tmr.ALARM_SEMI manually repeating alarm (call tmr.start() to
>   restart)

[tmr.ALARM_SEMI is equal to 2](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/tmr.c#L60). Based on that, this should work:

```
tmr.alarm(0, 500, 2, function()
      print("I'm here")
      tmr.stop(0)

      -- do some stuff

      tmr.start(0)
 end)
```

Comment: The documentation is not clear if you even need to call stop on an alarm_semi, i suspect that you dont need to.

Comment: Hi Nifim Thanks
That sounds reasonable - I will try this on the weekend. The documentation does NOT state though that you cannot use tmr.start on an tmr.ALARM_AUTO alarm.